# Handling tabhost on android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost

I have four activities namely,

- Demo_tabActivity.java  [main activity]
- Tabhost.java

The below two activities are tabs of the above tabhost.java

- Tab_1.java
- Tab_2.java

The first activity(`Demo_tabActivity.java`) contains an edittext & button.The second(`Tabhost.java`) activity contains a Tabhost widget.The third & fourth activities contains textviews respectively.

The first activity is going to consume a web service by getting the input from the user  and returns some data on first tab(third activity) of a tabhost(second activity).

Well consuming of webservice is working well and returns the value perfectly,

but, the problem is, its showing the result on the separate page instead of showing on the tabhost.

**Demo_tabActivity.java**

```
 public class Demo_tabActivity extends Activity 
 {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
   private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_in);

       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
           String b;

         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

         //Use this to add parameters
         request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

         //Declare the version of the SOAP request
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;

         try 
         {
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

             SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

             if(result != null)
             {
              //Get the first property and change the label text

                b = result.toString();
                Intent itnt = new Intent(v.getContext(), Tab_1.class);
                itnt.putExtra("gotonextpage", b.toString());
                startActivity(itnt);
             }
             else
             {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NoResponse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
       });
       }
```

***NOTE: I've only doubt on if condition in the above code***

---

**Tab_1.java**

```
public class Tab_1 extends Activity 
{
TextView tv;
String result;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{   result = extras.getString("gotonextpage");  }
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_main2);
tv.setText(result);
}}
```

**Tabhost.java**

```
 public class Tabhost extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);


    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_1.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EDIT:
Demo_tabActivity.java

 public class Demo_tabActivity extends Activity 
 {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?
WDL";

  Button btnFar;
EditText txtFar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_in);

   btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
       String b;

     //Initialize soap request + add parameters
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

     //Use this to add parameters
     request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

     //Declare the version of the SOAP request
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     envelope.dotNet = true;

     try 
     {
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

         //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

         // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

         SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

         if(result != null)
         {
          //Get the first property and change the label text

            b = result.toString();
            Intent itnt = new Intent(v.getContext(), Tabhost.class);
            itnt.putExtra("gotonextpage", b.toString());
            startActivity(itnt);
         }
         else
         {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NoResponse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   });
   }



 public class Tabhost extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main1);
String result;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){   
    result = extras.getString("gotonextpage");  
    }


TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_1.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(intent);
 intent.putExtra("gotonextpage", result);
        startActivity(itnt);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab_2.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}


Tab_1.java

public class Tab_1 extends Activity 
{
TextView tv;
String result;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main2);

 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{   result = extras.getString("gotonextpage");  }
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_main2);
tv.setText(result);
}}
```

I didn't try but most likely you need to Run your TabHost in the Demo_tabActivity.java class. Because If you call your tab host class it will call tab one and tab two activities respectively. (depends on which tab is set to current tab in tab host). Try and let me know the result !

Comment: osayilgan, if i place Tabhost.class instead of Tab_1.java it just showing the  tabhost widget with no answers.

Comment: What data you try to get, do try to get in Tab_1.java. Because you are calling the Tab_1.java with the result you get in your first activity.

Comment: Or I have a better way, you can call your tab host with this extra content that you put Tab_1.java from your first acitivity, and then get extra content there in tab host and then call Tab_1.java by getting and then putting this extra data.

Comment: put extra content to the tab host and and get this extra content to put in the intent that you call Tab_1.java. After that you will get this extra data in your Tab_1 activity. Just a bit longer way, that you already do. But don't forget to convert it to string before you put extra content, I guess I didn't write it.

Comment: Demo_tabActivity.java is containing the main concept,then how can i put the extra content to the tabhost.java?

Comment: i've tried what you have given above,but its simply showing the tabhost.java with no answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12984/discussion-between-rohith-and-osayilgan)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use TabGroupActivity to display every activity inside a TabHost. Check this link out on TabGroupActivity and see how it works. This will display your tabs in whatever activity you launch.This should solve your problem. http://androidmaterial.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-us-tab-group-activity-in-android.html

Comment: This should get your work done, I had a similar problem and implemented using it and it works perfectly well

Comment: can you tell me what i have to mend with my project...what thing i did wrong there.

Comment: copy the TabGroupActivity class to your project and instead of extending Activity extend the TabGroupActivity class for Tab_1 and Tab_2. Then use startChildActivity() from within each tab, which will let your tabs be visible. It is clearly mentioned in the link provided.